# Does anyone know how to create a interactive graphs using flare or other visualisation classes?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flare

Does anyone know of software or flex/flash/as3 source or visualisation software that could be used to make interactive graphs, where the user would enter a query that would pull data from a MySQL database and the user would build a sunburst or icicle graph by dragging and dropping items into a tree-like structure and they would be able to view the graph? i have attempted to use [flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) but my programming skills are pretty bad. So far from what i gather, flare only allows the graphing of defined datasets rather than allowing a user to modify the dataset and thus creating a new dataset.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

This is far too big for the scope of a single question.  You're going to need to write at least a few different pieces.
1.) Access to the database and a way to view datasets
2.) Control handlers to drag and drop datasets onto your chart object
3.) A chart object that can handle receiving dropped dataset items and render itself accordingly.

There are lots of good charting frameworks out there including Flare, Axiis, Flex charting, Fusion Charts, iLog Elixir.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do but any one of those should be able to serve as your charting piece.

Comment: I've had a look at most of them but none of them allow a user to drag and drop items to build a tree from an sql dump into a zero-item tree. :(

Comment: Any one of those will do what you need - just not out of the box.  You're going to have to do more development than that.

Answer (score 0):

We worked on a project that used Flare and Flex. We had to provide the data to Flare in an XML format called GraphML, so we had code to convert the data into the required format in our C# backend, and then we passed it to Flex. There were naff all tutorials for it though, so took some time to figure it out.

There is a properly cool graphing tool (although its commercial) called [Kapit](http://lab.kapit.fr/demo/diagrammer/prod/index.html#app=3573&d62c-selectedIndex=0&bde0-selectedIndex=2). Check out their Diagrammer and Visualizer [demos](http://lab.kapit.fr/demo/diagrammer/prod/index.html#app=3573&d62c-selectedIndex=0&bde0-selectedIndex=2). It could be the case that its worth the spend.

But I agree with Mr Owen, theres some mad scope in that question:)

Comment: Hey brian. i have looked at Kapit. It's pretty decent but i'm more interested in drag and drop method to build a tree from an SQL dump.